# How many Quran Book can We Keep at home?

Tags: mushaf

Is it a sin to keep more than one mushaf at home.I read from only one mushaf and the other three are locked in my cupboard.Should I keep them as it is or should I donate them to people ???

Comment: Could you explain why you think it would be a sin?? Your response would help us fix misconceptions among the community.

Answer (score 1):

There's no minimum nor maximum amount of Moshafs you may keep at home.

Please note that from a historical perspective Moshafs are rather an innovation of the time of the Sahabah as except with private copies of some Sahabah -who were scribes and memorizers- the qur'an was only ever since orally transmitted from generation to generation.
Therefore except with the necessary respect to a Moshaf's content anything else related on how to keep such a book is rather baseless assumption.

Further note that a Moshaf is the written content of the Qur'an, which is Allah's word and revelation and the minimum respect for that is using it and reading it as a remainder and for remembrance of Allah. Therefore it is certainly better to have it in use than as decoration. In case one would fear not using it, it is much better to donate it to people who may not have the means to purchase or have/get one.

Also note that some scholars actually regard selling Moshafs as frowned upon.